# What are the components used for the iPhone-sized car hack?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, automotive, security

Recently two security researchers hacked a car with iPhone-sized gadget according to [this link](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2014/02/05/this-iphone-sized-device-can-hack-a-car-researchers-plan-to-demonstrate/).

They didn't release any technical details, but I think we can guess from the picture of the gadget:

[image: Device image]

That it's based on some popular components like Arduino pro, and it uses Bluetooth.

I would like to identify all electronic components used in this hack starting from the published picture.

Comment: They didn't go into technical details to prevent people from replicating their work. Whether this is for legal or illegal use, we don't do speculation here.

Comment: [Technical details here](http://jalopnik.com/hackers-can-take-over-your-car-with-this-simple-26-dev-1519896807?utm_source=recirculation&utm_medium=recirculation&utm_campaign=tuesdayAM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. Might be CAN interface
2. Might be CAN interface
3. [Arduino pro mini](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini)
4. [Serial-Bluetooth link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/200927863479?lpid=82&item=200927863479&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466)
5. [LC-Tech SD Card Module](http://www.lctech-inc.com/Hardware/Default.aspx?Id=38dab293-e293-4022-9a8b-9c5abf4b9fe5)

It is really just a wireless link to the CAN bus as far as I can see. The components aren't the important part -- it is the software/firmware they are running.

Comment: Other articles state that the device simply links to the CAN bus to read/modify the firmware. This type of device just makes it very easy for them to interface.

Comment: @Thebluefish any links ?

Comment: [Finally remember where I found that article :)](http://jalopnik.com/hackers-can-take-over-your-car-with-this-simple-26-dev-1519896807?utm_source=recirculation&utm_medium=recirculation&utm_campaign=tuesdayAM)